# php exec() can work in wamp but can't read image

Tags: php, wamp

I want to upload a image and read the image to my program as an argument.
The upload part is OK.The exec() can work on hello.exe(just print "Hello world!"),but it can't work on my program(ImageAesthetic2013.exe)
Here is my code

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
}else{
echo "File name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br/>";
echo "File type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"]."<br/>";
echo "File size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024)." Kb<br />";
echo "temp name: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}

exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ImageAesthetic2013.exe C:\\wamp\\www\\Lena.jpg",  $output,$return_var);
exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\hello.exe", $out);
var_dump($out);
var_dump($output);
print_r($return_var);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK. Thank you!
But this is release build problem.
File put into WWW folder can solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As the PHP manual notes,

> In Windows, exec() issues an internal call to "cmd /c your_command". This implies that your command must follow the rules imposed by cmd.exe which includes an extra set of quotes around the full command:
>
> http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html
>
> Current PHP versions take this into account and add the quotes automatically, but old versions didn't.
>
> Apparently, the change was made in PHP/5.3.0 yet not backported to 5.2.x because it's a backwards incompatible change. To sum up:
>
> - In PHP/5.2 and older you have to surround the full command plus arguments in double quotes
> - In PHP/5.3 and greater you don't have to (if you do, your script will break)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.I use php5.4.12,so can you for example?